# iTextPdf - Android Studio Adding Library Error

Tags: android, android-studio, compiler-errors, shared-libraries, addition

I want to add itext lib to my project.(http://itextpdf.com/itextg-android)

I added to jar file into libs folder. After that i wrote to build.gradle that : compile files('libs/itextg-5.5.4.jar') .

But after the sync , i am getting that error :

> Error:(12, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'compile()'
>   Possible causes:
>
> The project 'Pdf' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
>   Gradle settings
>
> The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
>   Apply Gradle plugin

Also here(http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/986574/Android-iText-Pdf-Example) is a solution about this but when i do that i am getting another error

> Error:Failed to resolve: org.apache.commons:commons-imaging:1.0-SNAPSHOT
>   Open File
> Show in Project Structure dialog

Comment: go though this link. It might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16608135/android-studio-add-jar-as-library

Answer (score 2):

Please check if you added all needed packages and after this your `buil.gradle` looks like:

> ```
> apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
>
> android {
>     compileSdkVersion 22
>     buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"
>
>     defaultConfig {
>         applicationId "com.proyecto.alberto.monedero"
>         minSdkVersion 16
>         targetSdkVersion 22
>         versionCode 1
>         versionName "1.0"
>     }
>     buildTypes {
>         release {
>             minifyEnabled false
>             proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
>         }
>     }
> }
>
> dependencies {
>     compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
>     compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
>     compile files('libs/itextg-5.5.4.jar')
>     compile files('libs/itextg-5.5.4-sources.jar')
>     compile files('libs/itextg-5.5.4-javadoc.jar')
>     compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.0.0'
> }
> ```
>
> From: https://github.com/alonsoat/ProyectoMonedero/blob/master/app/build.gradle

Hope it help

Comment: I am taking error again : Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

Comment: try to change to jdk8

Comment: i updated my java but it did not work. Also here is a solution but when i do that i am getting error .

Answer (score 1):

You can also add a .jar or a library via right clicking on 
["app" > New > Module](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VzieA.jpg)

Then select the 
[Import .JAR/.AAR Package option.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FpoGk.jpg)

You can click the "browse" [...] on the far right and locate your jar.
Sync the project right click app > Sync app

You should be golden after that.
Alt-Shift over RED methods/code relevant to your added library and you should now be able to quick import.

Just another option.

Comment: After doing that i am taking this error : Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

Comment: @lovekrand One or more of the .jar files you added may not be compiling, hence they might not be written well. Is the library from a trusted source or is it like a Google API? You might try to remove the added libraries, and add them in one at a time.

Comment: Also, try to see if there may be duplicate Class files in your project tree, or maybe even written into the library you added. Sometimes Gradle builds are a little wonky after adding libraries for some reason.

Comment: One more thing, in your project tree, under Gradle Scripts > build.gradle(Module: yourApp). Open it and look under dependencies, do you see the libraries you added? If not try to re sync the project.

Comment: I made this there is no error but i can not import the itext methods, also i tried add library from project structure. But then i am getting error !!!